# Number of saves on wayback machine in python

Tags: python

How can I find the amount of times a website has been archived, ever, on the Wayback Machine using Python?

Couldn't get it to work using documentation, but I'm probably just being dense.

Tried this:

```
def wayback_response():
    for record in wayback_client.search("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"):
        momento = wayback_client.get_momento(record)
    print(momento)
```

Got a 503 Server Error

Comment: A 503 is a service error, and it could be caused by the service being broken, or a malformed request. What version of the library are you using? Is this a documented bug? If you can reproduce it, and it's still supported, may be worth submitting a bug report.